# Making the table border transparent

Tags: html, css

hi i want to make my table borders transparent. The code is

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;border-style:hidden;">
     <tr><td><a href="austria.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a></td>
<td><a href="france.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a></td>
<td><a href="germany.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="hongkong.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a>
<td><a href="italy.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a>
<td><a href="netherlands.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a></tr>
<tr><td><a href="prague.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a>
<td><a href="southkorea.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a>
<td><a href="sweden.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a></tr>
<tr><td><a href="uk.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a>
<td><a href="us.html"><img src="images/as.jpg"></a></tr></table>
```

Comment: Set `border-color: transparent;`

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid transparent">
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

use following css for your table tag

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 1em 2px; // horizontally: 2px, vertically 1em
}
```